# How to generate compile error for not completed enum to string conversion?

Tags: c++, enums, compiler-errors

We have something like this:

```
Enum IdEnum 
{
    Id_1,
    Id_2
}


GetNameById(IdEnum Id) : string
{
    switch Id
    {
        case Id_1 : return "1";
        case Id_2 : return "2";
    }
}
```

Is there any way to generate compile error if we add Id_3 to enum, but don't add **case** statement for it in GetNameById ?

Comment: C++ i've edited tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html:

> -Wswitch Warn whenever a switch statement has an index of enumerated type and lacks a case for one or more of the named codes of that
>   enumeration. (The presence of a default label prevents this warning.)
>   case labels outside the enumeration range also provoke warnings when
>   this option is used (even if there is a default label). This warning
>   is enabled by -Wall.
>
> -Wswitch-enum Warn whenever a switch statement has an index of enumerated type and lacks a case for one or more of the named codes of
>   that enumeration. case labels outside the enumeration range also
>   provoke warnings when this option is used. The only difference between
>   -Wswitch and this option is that this option gives a warning about an omitted enumeration code even if there is a default label.

Comment: Exactly what i need. Thank you.